# WhatsApp video URL?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there a specific server address from which WhatsApp serves the video (and image) files that users share?

I want to allow the use of WhatsApp and the exchange of text messages and video calls but block video files by blocking the file hosting server.

In other words:

When a user sends a video or image to another user, where are the videos hosted before the receiving user downloads them to their device?

Comment: There is long list of domains and IP addresses which may keep on changing. Instead consider blocking ports used for VoIP calling.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I don't mean video calls, but video files sent from one user to another.

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong. Here's a list you can try: https://pastebin.com/dd7RMcZr. A more easy approach would be to capture DNS traffic when downloading/opening videos in WhatsApp app.

Comment: Thank you, @IrfanLatif. This brief article may give the answer: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/169299/block-photovideo-files-upload-transfer.html It does refer to some of the URLs you have listed.

Comment: More explanation: http://www.rtcbits.com/2018/05/how-are-imagesvideos-sent-in-whatsapp.html and https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2017/07/21/china-can-censor-whatsapp-really-easily/#1f22e91f57e9